# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (Cannot built my app when i select iOS device)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, zbar, mach-o

I built an app that uses `ZbarSDK` for barcode scan, the app works fine when running over the simulator, but when I try to archive it on a real device this error shows up:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling your app for the `armv7s` architecture but ZbarSDK isn’t compiled for `armv7s`. So either compile ZbarSDK for `armv7s` (preferred) or don’t compile your app for `armv7s`.